# NSMutable Array difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Beginner iOS dev here. I have a problem in my array. Im making an app with iCarousel. That whenever it stop to a view it will delete the current view or index, like this:

```
    NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
    [carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
    [images removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

So my array have an index with this:

0 1 2 3 4 5

when I use the method above ( for example it lands on view 3) it become like this:

0 1 2 4 5

How to remain the same array index/value even if I delete? or should I update it?

I tried using `[carousel reloadData];` but still no effect.

Comment: What would you like to see in your result instead of `0 1 2 4 5`?

Comment: I wanted to maintain there index number even though they are deleted, I'm really having difficulty with this array.

Comment: So you want the result to be 0 1 2 3 4?

Comment: i still wand their indexes to be the same like this 1 2 blank 4 5

Comment: your question is absolutely unclear. Just specify what your array is before your code does something on it and what you want your output array to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[carousel replaceItemAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];`
and check if the object is of type `NSNull` then do nothing or according to your requirement.

Comment: Inder is correct. Simply replace object with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need a @synthesize call in the implementation.
Code:

```
@synthesize myNSMutableArray;
```

2) use "self." to use the setter/getters produced by the parameters.
Code:

```
self.myNSMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"object1.png", @"object2.png", @"object3.png", nil];
[self.myNSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: @"newObject.png"];

Without the "self." you are changing the iVar directly.
```