# Deleting in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have an array here, example I have 4 images on each column, each responds to its default index: 
[image]

When an image is deleted for example index 1. as shown in the image below:

[image]

The index becomes 0,1,2 :

[image]

which I want to be is 0,2,3 (Which is the original array index):

[image]

Could anyone help me on how to achieve this?

my code for my array:

```
self.myImages = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]]; 
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: show your code...Not images !

Comment: Don't delete from the array, just keep track of which indices are valid using another array.

Comment: May we ask _why_ you want to achieve this? There are surely better ways.

Comment: how to  keep track of which indices are valid using another array.?

Comment: Im really kinda new to iOS so what are the better ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can put another key in your dictionary which will correspond to the index before any removal of objects. Display it instead of the index and you will get the desired result.

edit 2:

```
self.myImages = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]]; 
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        NSMutableDictionary *container = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [container setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] forKey:@"image"];
        [container setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index"];
        [images addObject:container];
        [container release]; // if not using ARC 
    } 
}
```

And when you're getting the corresponding object, you do:

```
NSDictionary *obj = [images objectAtIndex:someIndex];
UIImage *objImg = [obj objectForKey:@"image"];
int objIndex = [[obj objectForKey:@"index"] intValue];
```

Comment: I'm getting my image from NSDocumentDirectory, so how will I add dictionary to it?

Comment: Not to the image, you're adding these images to a NSMutableArray (the one you mention in the title). While adding the images, add an index, too. I edited my post with a code example.

Comment: So when I delete like this [images removeObjectAtIndex:index]; it would be [images removeObjectAtIndex:objIndex]; ?

Comment: No, you should delete objects the way you're doing it now.

Comment: Im having trouble deleting it with this :                        `NSInteger index = carousel1.currentItemIndex;
        [carousel1 removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
        [items1 removeObjectAtIndex:index]; `

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943332/1041847) should help you solve your last issue.

Comment: I don't know, haven't used the iCarousel framework. Post it as a new question.

Comment: What? I haven't used any iCarousel objects, so I can't help you with this. You asked for a solution for a NSMutableArray and I gave you a functioning one. For this second question (how to remove objects from iCarousel framework object), I'm not capable of answering.

Comment: no not in iCarouse but in array, thats what I'm having problem with. so how to delete item/index in array using your code

Comment: `[images removeObjectAtIndex:index];`

Answer (score 1):

use an NSMutableDictionary instead

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setValue:@"Item 0" forKey:@"0"];
[dictionary setValue:@"Item 1" forKey:@"1"];
[dictionary setValue:@"Item 2" forKey:@"2"];
[dictionary setValue:@"Item 3" forKey:@"3"];

//    0 = "Item 0";
//    1 = "Item 1";
//    2 = "Item 2";
//    3 = "Item 3";
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);

//Remove the item 1
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"1"];

//    0 = "Item 0";
//     2 = "Item 2";
//    3 = "Item 3";
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
```

Comment: I'm getting my image from NSDocumentDirectory.

Comment: Add them to an NSMutableDictionary and add the index @"0" @"1" etc.. as keys

Comment: how to delete in here:  `NSInteger index = carousel1.currentItemIndex; [carousel1 removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES]; [items1 removeObjectAtIndex:index]; `