# NSMutableArray index mixed up

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm currently trying the `iCarousel` `Multiple Carousel` example.
Here in my array, I've add images with NSMutableDictionary:

I have two of these: ( myImages and myImages2 for my two slot in carousel loaded in ViewDidLoad)

```
self.myImages = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]]; 
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedPath]){ 
        NSMutableDictionary *container = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [container setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedPath] forKey:@"image"];
        [container setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index"];
        [images addObject:container];
        [container release]; // if not using ARC 
    } 
}
```

in my iCarousel:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        NSDictionary *obj = [items1 objectAtIndex:index];
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"items1"]];
        view.tag = index;
    }else
    {
        NSDictionary *obj = [items2 objectAtIndex:index];
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"items2"]];
        view.tag = index;
    }

    return view;
}
```

In another View, these arrays are also loaded, the user has a chance to pick an image to compare to with,

when an user pick an image an int equivalent to its tag is pass to where my two Carousel is.

Here is how I compare them:

```
NSInteger image = [prefs integerForKey:@"image"];
NSInteger image1 = [prefs integerForKey:@"image2"];

        if (image == [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel1 currentItemView] tag] || image2= [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || ) {
```

I delete an index this way:

```
    NSInteger index = carousel1.currentItemIndex;
    [carousel1 removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
    [items1 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

I think I'm deleting it the wrong away, because the index arent updated, what i wanted is to maintain its index not adjust like this images right here:

[Deleting in NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203568/deleting-in-nsmutablearray)

Comment: Looking at this post, and your other post, I can't see the problem.  In standard dynamic arrays, when an item is removed, all other items' indexes are updated.  In this case you should never have a situation where you have removed item 1 from a list 0, 1, 2, 3 and end up with 0, 2, 3.  The correct resultant array is 0, 1, 2!!!

Comment: but Im really having problem comparing the picked imageView(tagged view) with my carouselVIew, So Im thinking that there something wrong with my array, I really dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Is this really your code, because you have an extra || (or) at the end of your if within your compare

Comment: What is "prefs" within the same compare?

Comment: NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; sorry for incomplete

Comment: Im still trying to understand what you are truly trying to compare in order to delete an item?  What logically are you trying to obtain as the case to delete?

Comment: like a matching game. if they are only compared it will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do now, which is to move the two carousels until the middle one matches, then to not have the indexes simply go away, then you could just rather than removing the item from the array, fill the location you are trying to delete with a nil image (or a valid image with the backing of your choosing), and a tag stating it has already been matched.

This is all of course dependent on whether my understanding of what you want is valid.

Comment: not the middle but a user picked image/index from another view. like a users choice then delete. what do you mean by nil image? how?

Comment: a UIImageView will display nothing if set to nil, or in your other post, you have a blue backing, your could have a simple image with nothing more than a blue backing (same as your background) so assign to all deleted images.

Comment: Also, how will a user pick an image to delete from you carousels before seeing the carousels?  You said they are supposed to pick an image from another view.  Again, still trying to understand better what you are trying to accomplish!!!

Comment: images from my carousel are from my camera roll, which i save in documentdirectory then load it in another view like a setting view, then the user will pick who it wants to be matched together, then in the carousel view, the carousel will do a rotating effect/shuffling effect, then compare the two if its the same as the users choice then it will stop if not continues rotating.