# NSUserDefaults in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to set/make this into an NSMutableArray?

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"KeyI1"];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"KeyJ1"];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"KeyI2"];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"KeyJ2"];
```

Which I can use for an if statement something like this:

```
NSInteger I1=[prefs integerForKey:@"KeyI1"];
NSInteger I2=[prefs integerForKey:@"KeyI2"]
NSInteger J1=[prefs integerForKey:@"KeyJ1"]
NSInteger J2=[prefs integerForKey:@"KeyJ2"]

if ( I1 == index1 && K1 == index2){

}
if ( I2 == index1 && K2 == index2){

}
```

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `setInteger:` for `NSUserDefaults` (which uses a `NSMutableDictionary` structure) directly. You should use `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` and add your integers in `NSNumber` objects or write a `NSMutableDictionary` [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) that will handle `setInteger:forKey:` and `integerForKey:`.

Comment: I addded NSMutableDictionary to my object array, want to be able to get their indexes.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, paraphrase please.

Comment: like this in my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209480/nsmutablearray-index-mixed-up

Comment: Do you understand that I'm answering to the concrete questions you ask  in each separate thread I respond to and not some other elsewhere?